# Reading EXPRESS/IFC files and writing .dwg or .dxf

Tags: c#, converters, libraries

I'm working on a project where I want to convert .step/.stp files (using EXPRESS and/or IFC) into a .dwg or .dxf file. I am slowly struggling through the data structre. Are there alternative ways instead of figuring out all attributes by myself?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: I rephrased my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is creating many confusions around.

First of all IFC Schema is EXPRESS based schema or EXPRESS Schema. You will get IFC schema from "Building Smart" website, It comes with .exp extension. (.exp extension also states that IFC schema is express based or Express schema).

DWG is CAD file format and DXF is industry standard. (So there is big difference between .dwg and .dxf)

.dwg is format maily used/created by AutoCAD software.

So now if you want to convert "STEP(.stp,.step,.p21) to .dwg" then google is your best friend.

Quick Google search shows that there are some options available.